# Injection not working properly in Arquillian Tests - strange errors

Tags: cdi, jboss-eap-6, jboss-arquillian

I have a somewhat strange problem with Arquillian tests and CDI injections:

This bean works perfectly fine when it's being tested:

```
@RequestScoped
public class Greeter {

    @Inject
    protected GreetingProvider greetingProvider;

    public String doGreeting(String greet) {
        System.out.println("Information: greetingProvider=" + greetingProvider);

        return String.format("%s, %s!", greetingProvider.getGreetingWord(), greet);
    }

}
```

with the only exception, that in the following test case the method  "testGreetingProviderInGreeterIsNotNull()" always fails

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class GreeterTest {

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        WebArchive deployment = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                .addClass(Greeter.class)
                .addClass(GreetingProvider.class)
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml") ;

        return deployment;
    }

    @Inject
    private Greeter greeter;

    @Test
    @InSequence(1)
    public void testGreeterIsInjectedProperly() {
        assertNotNull(greeter);
    }

    @Test
    @InSequence(2)
    public void getGreetingTest() {
        String name = "John";
        String expected = "Hello, " + name + "!";
        String actual = greeter.doGreeting(name);
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    @Test
    @InSequence(3)
    public void testGreetingProviderInGreeterIsNotNull() {
        assertNotNull(greeter.greetingProvider);
    }


}
```

I do not understand why, cause if the field greetingProvider were null also the second test method should fail.

What's my error?

The full source code is available on GitHub:
https://github.com/t3chris/ArquillianInjectionTests

Comment: --What's the failure?-- Never mind I can just clone and run it :)

Comment: I haven't looked my further, but the server is complaining that the beans.xml file isn't found. I can clearly see it in your test though.

Comment: Failure/Problem:
When I try to access greetingProvider through the reference greeter.greetingProvider from the test class, then this reference seems to be null. But that can't be, otherwise the second test would not work. As injection in Greeter works fine I assume that there is a beans.xml

Answer (score 0):

I believe, but not 100% sure, it's because you're missing an `arquillian.xml` in your `src/test/resources` folder that should force the default protocol to Servlet 3.  By default, in AS7/EAP6 the protocol is their JMX protocol.  When you use their JMX protocol the `RequestScope` is not active for the interaction.

Your arquillian.xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />
</arquillian>
```

Comment: Just tried that, but unfortunately it doesn't make any difference. 

I've also verified if arquillian.xml is in the right location by toggling the deploymentExportPath setting. 

I think that the @RequestScoped is respected cause the actual injection into Greeter works - it's just not visible from the test...

Comment: Oh duh sorry.  The reason that `greetingProvider` is null when you try to access the variable is because CDI will assign a proxy to it at runtime when you try to do something with it.  However, you cannot access the field of a bean when you're using proxies directly when you're outside that bean.  It should actually work if you use a getter, but either way you shouldn't be accessing the fields, as per the CDI spec.

Comment: Sorry, pressed Enter too early. The reason why I'm asking is because I want to replace a EJB without an interface (@Localbean) by a mock implementation. Therefore I just wanted to overwrite this reference. Is there any other way to mock an EJB or Webservice without an Interface in Arquillian?

Comment: Well mocking defeats the purpose of Arquillian :) try using a package level setter to set the value.